# how to add user controls as listbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox, listboxitem

I am using WPF .net 4.5 (c#) and I would like to make a ListBox that contains a series of user controls.  (If a listbox is the wrong type of control, please let me know).

I want my listbox to have a copy of the user control as the list items, with different contents within each one.

How do I add user controls to a listbox?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Read this first. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set ItemTemplate for the listbox with your usercontrol in it.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can design a DataTemplate which ha the same UI or Style as this UserControl .
maybe just copy paste can get a DataTemplate as you want,however

```
 <DataTemplate>
  <local:UserControl1/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

this king seems very strange for me I dont konw it can work as you want,so I also want to know
the answers。

Comment: Answer if you have an answer please.