# Using a Usercontrol inside Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a datatemplate with following code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TplFullImages" 
    DataType="{x:Type cControl:FullVisableImageControl}">
</DataTemplate>
```

`cControl:FullVisableImageControl` is my usercontrol

However I still need the Usercontrol to have the parameters when it initializes. How can I achieve this and what other options do I have?

Comment: What kind of parameters? Your `DataTemplate` is empty at the moment. Also, `DataTemplate` determines, how a data object (model or view model) is presented in GUI. I don't understand, why your `DataType` is set to a control type. Maybe `ControlTemplate` is what you're after? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_controltemplates

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is this:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="TplFullImages">
    <cControl:FullVisableImageControl}" Property="Value"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`DataTemplate.DataType` is used when a property from your model is of type set in `DataType`, and you bind one of the controls to this property. Considering you've specified the `x:Key` attribute, this is not what you want to do.

For examples of using `DataTemplate.DataType` see [MSDN: DataTemplate.DataType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the similar one yesterday. Please check if it helps.

[how to add user controls as listbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552716/how-to-add-user-controls-as-listbox-items/18552749#18552749)

Thanks