# Custom UserControl with nested UserControls in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox

I am trying to get a custom [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to render in a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx), but nothing is being rendered. I came across [this question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552716/how-to-add-user-controls-as-listbox-items) which works for the simple example, but my situation is a little different. I have a `PersonControl` for a `Person` object and a `CoupleControl` that can reference two `PersonControl` controls.

I've tried a couple things in the `CoupleControl` which haven't worked. I commented out one of the ways:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Control:PersonControl Grid.Column="0"
                           x:Name="LeftPerson" />
    <Control:PersonControl Grid.Column="1"
                           x:Name="RightPerson" />
    <!-- This is how I'd like to do it in case I create other controls
         I wish to replace the PersonControls (e.g. AnimalControl) -->
    <!--<UserControl Grid.Column="0"
                     x:Name="LeftPerson" />-->
    <!--<UserControl Grid.Column="1"
                     x:Name="RightPerson" />-->
</Grid>
```

The relevant WPF snippet for the list box:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Control:CoupleControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<CoupleControl> Persons { get; private set; }

Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Smith", Person.SexType.Male);
Person jane = new Person("Jane", "Smith", Person.SexType.Female);

PersonControl joeControl = new PersonControl();
PersonControl janeControl = new PersonControl();
joeControl.DataContext = joe;
janeControl.DataContext = jane;
CoupleControl coupleControl = new CoupleControl();
coupleControl.LeftPerson.DataContext = joe;
coupleControl.RightPerson.DataContext = jane;
//coupleControl.LeftPerson.Content = joeControl;    // Also doesn't work
//coupleControl.RightPerson.Content = janeControl;  // Also doesn't work

Persons.Add(coupleControl);
```

Can someone help me get the CoupleControl to render in a ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is a bit too code-heavy for my taste, why not set DataContext in XAML?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Control:PersonControl DataContext="{Binding LeftPerson}" />
    <Control:PersonControl DataContext="{Binding RightPerson}" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Or maybe even drop `UserControls` altogether if they are not so complex? In this case using `DataTemplates` can be faster and simpler. Say we defined templates for `Person` and `Couple` in Window resources (Couple is just a class with LeftPerson and RightPerson properties):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="personTemplate" DataType="TestWPF:Person">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green" CornerRadius="5">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

         <DataTemplate x:Key="coupleTemplate" DataType="TestWPF:Couple">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ContentControl Content="{Binding LeftPerson}"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource personTemplate}" />
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding RightPerson}" 
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource personTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you set `ItemTemplate` for your ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource coupleTemplate}" />
```

This way you can make some more templates for the types you need and just set them in ListBox in one single line.